# How to override a components props where the component itself is a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following component which receives a prop called button.

This button prop is actually a Component itself and within it there are some props.

I wish to override the prop called *type* within there. Is this possible?

```
// I only have access to this class and looking to work within here.
// button is the component below.
// I want to override the prop type that is being passed in there.
const MyClass = ({
  button
}) => {
  // tried following but throws synax errors
  // return props => <button type={'overridenValue'} {...props} />;
  return button;
};

export default MyClass;


// I do not have access to this class
// nor the point at which this is created.
const Button = ({type}) => (
  <div></div>
);

export default Button;
```

Edit:

Elaborating on what I am trying to achieve.

As mentioned above I am receiving a component which has a set of props already in it. I wish to override / replace / or make a copy of this component so that I can change one of the props in this component.

That prop is called *type*. Ultimately the prop is a Type of color. Like Type.White or Type.Blue and so on. When I receive the component, it comes with the value Type.White. I want to change it to Type.Blue. As the name suggests it changes the color of the button.

The button is a lot more complex with more props in it with routing details and others. Thus I need those details to be unchanged. I only want to change the Type value.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The Type is coming into me with a default value. This is fine in most instance but not for all. In one scenario I need it to be a different type. Ant I am not the one passing the value. Thus trying to override at this stage.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, though. What are you trying to _actually do_ that you thought this code would let you do? Not "what code did you write" but "what functionality or idea are you trying to implement here".

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The ability to over ride the type, so that I can have a different type passed into the component so that it render differently. Example the type is a color type. It always default to the color White. By this ability to override, I pass in the color Blue and now able to render it differently even though the Component was initially passed to me with the color white.

Comment: Remember that we have no idea what your code looks like: that description still does not explain much. You're still just saying what you're doing in this post, not what you're trying to _achieve_ with this code. Please update your post to give an example of what you're trying to do, as a real example, and what you expect your code to do (if it worked. The fact that it doesn't does not factor into that description\).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Updated the question. Hope this clarifies better.

Comment: I see you accepted an answer but your code is okay - you just needed to capitalize your button prop - {  button: Button } and use it like <Button {...props} /> or use dot notiaion - <props.button /> - you can't use lowercase names for components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`cloneElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) to achieve this. The second parameter for `cloneElement` is a `props` object that will let you do exactly what you're asking:

> The resulting element will have the original element’s props with the new props merged in shallowly.

[Here's a simple demo in StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-v1gu95). The caller is passing an `input` of type `text` to the wrapper -

```
<Wrapper component={<input id="component" type="text" data-name="some-name" />} />
```

The wrapper then creates a clone of this element and overrides the `type` to be a `checkbox`:

```
const { component } = props;
const nextProps = { type: 'checkbox' };
const Component = React.cloneElement(component, nextProps);
```

Then in the rendered output, you can see that the properties from the original `input` have been passed, but the `type` has been replaced:

```html
<input id="component" type="checkbox" data-name="some-name">
```